# OracleDB - Substring (group by and order by)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

For some reason, I can't get this query to work.

```
select substr(x.id, 4, 5)
from x
join y
on x.id=y.x_id 
where 1=1
group by substr(x.id, 4, 5)
order by substr(x.id, 4, 5) asc
```

It keeps saying:
    ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
    00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select substr(x.id, 4, 5) as col
    from x
    join y
    on x.id=y.x_id 
    where 1=1
    group by substr(x.id, 4, 5)
)
order by col asc
```

Is it possible to do it without using a subquery?

Comment: Your first query works on SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/911b0/1).

Comment: If you're not going to use any group functions (e.g. count(*)), you can just do a `select distinct` and remove the `group by`, but Gordon is correct, what you have should work.

Comment: I need to use the group functions, so select distinct work unfortunately. It doesn't work on Oracle SQL Developer for some reason.

Comment: @sv94, can you confirm if the SQL you posted is exactly same SQL you are running on your side?

Comment: I am using 10g dialect, SQL Fiddle is using 11g. Perhaps that's why it works there.